# How to write @xml:space="preserve" with Stax

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, stax

I use stax to write a XML file.

My question is how can I add the attribute `xml:space="preserve"` to my elements?

- Do I need to declare the `xml` prefix? AFAIK, it is normally not necessay.

  - If I don't declare, stax complains that a preferred prefix cannot be `null` ( javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Prefix cannot be null)
  - If I declare the prefix with `setPrefix("xml", "http://www.w3.org/1998/xml")` on my `XMLStreamWriter`, it seems to have no effect. In debug mode, I see that the nsmap of the XMLStreamWriter has no entry for "xml"
- The exception is raised when I write the attribute with `writeAttribe("http://www.w3.org/1998/xml", "space", "preserve")`. Is there a specific method for this instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around:

```
writeAttribute("xml:space", "preserve")
```

but this is a non-sense because `xml:space` is not a local name, is it?